# AVRDUDE verification error

Tags: avr, avrdude

I've been working with AVR microcontrollers (specifically with ATmega328p's) for a bit and I got an ATmega32u4 that I wanted to program it to be used as a USB peripheral. However there is one problem: when I tried to flash a basic LED blink script to the AVR, AVRDUDE started sending back this weird error message:

```
avrdude.exe: verifying ...
avrdude.exe: verifying ...
avrdude.exe: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
             0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude.exe: verification error; content mismatch
```

Note: before AVRDUDE gets to this point it reads the device signature and writes the hex files that I sent to it. Like normal.

After it does this, it tells me that the lock bit values have changed and I should either leave them alone or restore them to default. (The lock bits are never really the same and not all of them have to be changed.)

I don't know if this is an AVRDUDE issue or a programmer issue. I hope it's not the latter, as it's a new USBasp.

Comment: Hi, can you ask a question you want answered?

Comment: Assuming the problem is the verification error (and presumably the programming not sticking either?), try looking at the fuses, especially JTAG and ISP settings, and clock.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't specific. I just want to know why I was getting this verification error. and @TimWilliams how do I look at the fuses? (Note: I'm using Avrdude 7.1 and I'm using it as an external Atmel studio tool.)

Comment: Use `-U lfuse:r:CON:b` and `hfuse`, or whichever locations are applicable to the device. You'll have to look up the bit positions in the manual. Usually Atmel Studio integrates this in the programming dialog (I haven't used it in forever).

Comment: @TimWilliams but doesn't -U specify how we program the chip? how would I modify the fuses with that?

Comment: Always check the manual: https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_3.html

Comment: If you reply to comments asking for clarification, please [edit] your question. Do not add a comment, this is not the place, and it will be overseen. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! (after a whole day of troubleshooting) it turns out that the supply current from my programmer was insufficient for programming. resulting in a verification error. I used an external power supply (which I believe has a higher output current) to power the microcontroller instead, and it worked! Thanks to everyone who commented above I'm still new to this site so forgive my incorrect etiquette.